can't build the project (NextJS)
When run in dev mode, it works, but I can't build my code to production.
this is my code
import React, {KeyboardEvent} from 'react'

interface InputProps{
    name: string,
    id: string,
    placeholder: string,
    onKeyDown?: (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;       
}


const Input = (props: InputProps) => {
    const {name, id, placeholder, onKeyDown} = props

    return (
        <input name={name} id={id} placeholder={placeholder} onKeyDown={onKeyDown} type="text" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-400 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5" required/>
    )
}

export default Input

This is the error:
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<InputProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'name' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I expected  my code to run ok in production

import React, { KeyboardEvent } from 'react';

interface InputProps {
   name: string;
   id: string;
   placeholder: string;
   onKeyDown?: (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;       
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ name, id, placeholder, onKeyDown }) 
=> {
return (
<input 
  name={name} 
  id={id} 
  placeholder={placeholder} 
  onKeyDown={onKeyDown} 
  type="text" 
  className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-400 text-gray-900 text-sm 
rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5" 
  required
/>
  );
 };

 export default Input;


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
